# AWS API Tools vs AWS CLI: ec2-import-instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, ec2-api-tools

I'm wondering... in the "new" AWS CLI tool, which would be the equivalent to the "old" `ec2-import-instance` command? Can't find anything useful in the AWS Docs, help output or on the web.

Reason why I'm asking is that I'm curious to see their Python implementation of it, as I want to incorporate it into my own code. AWS CLI uses Python/boto (as opposed to the old API tools which used Java), which might be an explanation why the functionality is missing (couldn't find it in boto either).

If you happen to know how to achieve an instance import in pure Python, I'd be very curious about that too!

Any pointers are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be supported in a later release. As of now, there is no support for it.

[For more info](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/911)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and pointer. Looks like I might have to deal with the HTTP/json API directly then. Tried to avoid that. I'll mark this as an answer, because that's probably the closest it gets to what's happening with boto, although not what I'd like to hear :)